# Why are the constraints set in Xcode ignored at load time and then applied at the completion of each rotation of the device?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have recently been learning to use UIStoryboard. It is great, but I have just one ViewController for which I can not get the Constraints right. All constraints are set inside Xcode. I am not using custom transitions.

The view is perfect, but ONLY after one or more rotations have occurs. It is as if the constraints are ignored at load time and then applied at the completion of each rotation of the device.

Storyboard Info:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgs73qy6az1czm2/Screenshot%202014-06-02%2010.38.01.png

ImageView Info:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtfeekxgyf944m3/Screenshot%202014-06-02%2010.52.57.png

Photo at Load Time:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xihohl23uzogt0v/AddPhotoInitial.jpg

Photo after First Rotation:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nmeswsoaziasge/AddPhotoAfterRotate.jpg

Please tell me what I am missing. Thank you very much.

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. The Xcode Attributes Inspector had Extend Edges - Under Bottom Bars checked. When I unchecked it. Everything appeared correctly at first load time.